# How to find and replace text with variable (variable holds Unix scripts) using sed or awk command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

Goal: I want to replace a string with content of file which has unix code.

What I'm trying to do is:

First:  I'm storing the contents of file to a variable

```
variable=`cat sample.sh`
variable2="$(sed -z 's:\n:\\\n:g;$s:\\\n$::'<<<"$variable")"
```

and then using that variable in sed command to replace the text with variable value.

```
sed -i "s:SearchString:$variable2//&/\\\&}:g"<<<"SearchString"  File.html
```

The sed command throws error  stating that

> sed: -e expression #, char 5: unknown option to s'

Please help to achieve my target.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please add 3 simple things, 1- Add sample Input file in code tags in your post. 2- Add expected output with all conditions with CODE TAGS, 3- what you have tried. Add these in your post and let us know then.

Comment: You need not to put your file's content into a variable and then reach variable with `sed`. `sed` itself could read the Input_file.

Comment: Can you please explain me in details, I'm new to unix and have less knowledge in shell script @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that you have a colon in $variable2, and that is terminating the substitution value. Is there a character that you know won't be in $variable2? For example, the "pipe" character "|" - if there is, use that character here rather than ":" to separate the parts of the "s" command.

I assume it's a typo, but you are missing the opening curly brace in "${variable2" in the sed command.

There are other ways to solve your problem, but this is the minuimum change.

Comment: you are right.. colon was terminating the substitution @simon3270, I used caret (^) character to separate the parts.                                                   
    Can you please suggest me any char/symbol which will not likely to be used in shell script(my input file is shell file), can I use the combination of symbols? like @@ or ::

Answer (score 0):

@GulamJeelani you're approaching this the wrong way with the wrong tool. sed is for doing s/old/new, **that is all**. See [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001) for **some** of the problems you'll face trying to force sed to do this job or anything else more complicated than s/old/new. Just use awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN { old = "SearchString" }
NR==FNR { new = (FNR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0; next }
s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
{ print }
' sample.sh File.html
```

The above is untested of course since you didn't provide sample input/output that we could test against but it should be very obvious what it's doing and how to tweak it if necessary.

Comment: Before appending sample.sh to HTML file I'm doing some processing on that sh file, So I'm holding it into some variable and then running the sed command, just FYI I have more number of files (15-20) and using awk will make my code look lengthier. @Ed Morton

Comment: If it does then you're almost certainly approaching the task the wrong way. More importantly though - using awk will work robustly, efficiently, portably, and be trivial to enhance later which should all be far more important than whether or not your code is a couple of lines longer even if that were the case. In your comment under the answer you accepted you said `suggest me any char/symbol which will not likely to be used in shell script` - that alone should be a huge red flag to you that your approach is wrong.

Comment: I'll look over the code and try to implement it in my code,Thank you @Ed Morton

Comment: You're welcome and, of course, feel free to post a new question on this site if you run into any issues.